# Unicode arrow characters used in Kali gedit

Tags: gedit, gedit-plugin

What unicode characters are used in the default kali gedit replacements for `->`. The gedit arrow seems to be used comprised of two characters. One arrow head and an extending long middle hyphen.

Gedit arrow:

[image]

PS: I want to use this specific arrow in my vscode setup. I find the other unicode arrows too small, therefore I need to use a 'compound character' (not sure if it's the correct term).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'll just use the fira code font which already does this.